# How to create IBOutlet one handed?

Tags: ios, xcode

For a disabled person (can only use one hand), is it possible to create an IBOutlet and IBAction in iOS programming?

At the moment we use ctrl, click drag however it is impossible for disabled person to do this. Any accebility tricks for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the `IBOutlet` or `IBAction` in code first. Then in your storyboard or xib, click on the thing that owns said `IBOutlet` or `IBAction`. Now, in Xcode's menu bar, go to `View->Inspectors->Show Connections Inspector`. Click down inside the little circle next to the name of the outlet/action that you're trying to connect, and drag your mouse over to the view (or whatever) that will be your outlet (or if you're trying to connect an action, then drag to the button or gesture recognizer or whatever that will be performing the action, and then select the appropriate event, like `touchUpInside` for a button for example).

Also, I recommend turning on Sticky Keys in your macOS settings if you can only use one hand (located at `Settings->Accessibility->Keyboard->Enable Sticky Keys`). This will let you press modifier keys down and then use that same hand to press other keys and still perform the key combination.